# How to read the response body as a string in Rust Hyper?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, hyper

This question has several answers ([here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/convert-hyper-body-to-string/23179), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148163/displaying-the-response-body-with-hyper-only-shows-the-size-of-the-body), and [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/async-book/issues/6)), but none of them worked for me :(

What I've tried so far:

```
    use hyper as http;
    use futures::TryStreamExt;

    fn test_heartbeat() {
        let mut runtime = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().expect("Could not get default runtime");

        runtime.spawn(httpserve());

        let addr = "http://localhost:3030".parse().unwrap();
        let expected = json::to_string(&HeartBeat::default()).unwrap();

        let client = http::Client::new();
        let actual = runtime.block_on(client.get(addr));

        assert!(actual.is_ok());

        if let Ok(response) = actual {
            let (_, body) = response.into_parts();
            
            // what shall be done here? 
        }
    }
```

I am not sure, what to do here?

Comment: Have you tried [to_bytes](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13.7/hyper/body/fn.to_bytes.html)? It returns a `Bytes` object which you can deref into a `&[u8]`, which you can then [interpret as utf-8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html).

Comment: I would also suggest [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) if you'd prefer ease of use over fine-grained control of hyper.

Comment: yep, that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [justinas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1264974/justinas) the answer is:

```
// ...
let bytes = runtime.block_on(hyper::body::to_bytes(body)).unwrap();
let result = String::from_utf8(bytes.into_iter().collect()).expect("");
```

Comment: even though it surely can be solved in a better way.

Comment: Note that if you are already inside async code, you should replace the `runtime.block_on` part with an `.await` like seen in the other answer.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me (using hyper 0.2.1):

```
async fn body_to_string(req: Request<Body>) -> String {
    let body_bytes = hyper::body::to_bytes(req.into_body()).await?;
    String::from_utf8(body_bytes.to_vec()).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: hyper::body::to_bytes() removed in 1.0,  `req.collect().await?.to_bytes();` works. (to_bytes() is now unfallible)